# XPath to find duplicate value pairs in different nodes

Tags: xpath

I have XML files not created by me which sometimes come with a duplicate pair of values. The two values are in different nodes, the structure that contains the pairs is repeated many times within the file. Ultimately I'm writing some python to adjust one value in the second instance of the duplication. Would someone help me with the XPath I need to return the absolute path of the HEADER/NUMBER in the last instance of the duplicated pair?
My file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BIGGEST>
  <MIDDLEST>
    <SMALLEST>
      <HEADER>
        <SOMETHING>ELSE</SOMETHING>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        <OTHER>
          <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        </OTHER>
      </HEADER>
    </SMALLEST>
    <SMALLEST>
      <HEADER>
        <SOMETHING>OTHER</SOMETHING>
        <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        <OTHER>
          <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        </OTHER>
      </HEADER>
    </SMALLEST>
    <SMALLEST>
      <HEADER>
        <SOMETHING>NEW</SOMETHING>
        <NUMBER>3</NUMBER>
        <OTHER>
          <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        </OTHER>
      </HEADER>
    </SMALLEST>
    <SMALLEST>
      <HEADER>
        <SOMETHING>BORROWED</SOMETHING>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        <OTHER>
          <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        </OTHER>
      </HEADER>
    </SMALLEST>
    <SMALLEST>
      <HEADER>
        <SOMETHING>BLUE</SOMETHING>
        <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        <OTHER>
          <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        </OTHER>
      </HEADER>
    </SMALLEST>
    <SMALLEST>
      <HEADER>
        <SOMETHING>TOO</SOMETHING>
        <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
        <OTHER>
          <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
        </OTHER>
      </HEADER>
    </SMALLEST>
  </MIDDLEST>
</BIGGEST>
```

I want to find when /BIGGEST/MIDDLEST/SMALLEST/HEADER/NUMBER and /BIGGEST/MIDDLEST/SMALLEST/HEADER/OTHER/NUMBER are duplicated in another SMALLEST.
In this example SMALLEST[2] and SMALLEST[6] are the same, so I want to return the following path: /BIGGEST/MIDDLEST/SMALLEST[6]/HEADER/NUMBER

Also this is a simplification of the file, there is quite a bit of data represented by SOMETHING. I say this to stop someone from suggesting I simply find duplicate SMALLESTs.

I'm very new to XPath, so I'm still struggling with the basic syntax of finding any duplicate values, let alone a pair of values in different nodes. This is just the first step toward my goal and I get this error: Unexpected token. The expression around '[NUMBER=folowing::/HEADER/NUMBER]' is not a valid instance of the XPath grammar.

```
/BIGGEST/MIDDLEST/SMALLEST/HEADER[NUMBER=folowing::/HEADER/NUMBER]
```

I think I provided enough, but please let me know what else would help.

Comment: Okay, i figured out I don't know how to spell following, But I still can't get it to work. :(

Comment: I think it's possible to get you `6` as the position of the `SMALLEST` element that has the same `NUMBER`  and `OTHER/NUMBER` values as another `SMALLEST` node, if that's what you are interested in.

Comment: @JackFleeting, I think that would work, the rest of the XML path will always be the same. If you can point me in the right direction, like what functions to use and what not I can take it from there. Thanks!

Comment: See the answer below.

Comment: @JackFleeting I get a 1 from the expression below. I understand  the count and concat functions, and finding multiple instances of the concatenation, but how does that work with the second preceding-sibling? Do you know of some article or tutorial I could read?

Comment: With the xml in your question, the output of the xpath expression below definitely `6`. It may, of course, be different for you actual xml.

Comment: Thank you @JackFleeting!  I found the typo in my XML. Works just as I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm short on time right now, I'll just post the expression for now. Please check it out and, if it works, I'll come back later to edit the answer and explain it. I used the following format for better readability only:

```
count(/BIGGEST/MIDDLEST/SMALLEST
[
concat(HEADER/NUMBER,HEADER/OTHER/NUMBER) 
= 
preceding-sibling::SMALLEST/concat(HEADER/NUMBER,HEADER/OTHER/NUMBER) 
]
/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```